# Query from 3 tables, lasts forever

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, mysql-workbench, database-performance

I am using `mysql-workbench` 6.3 on `Ubuntu 18.04.`

I have three tables created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `prefix_random` (
  `domain` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`domain`),
   UNIQUE KEY `domain_UNIQUE` (`domain`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Note: there are additional 32 fields but I do not query them, omitted for brevity.

Example:

```
domain
-----------------
sub.example.net
```

The second table:

```
CREATE TABLE `noprefix_random` (
  `domain` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domain`),
  UNIQUE KEY `domain_UNIQUE` (`domain`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Note: there are additional 32 fields but I do not query them, omitted for brevity.

Example:

```
domain
----------------------
example.net
```

The third table:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_random` (
  `new_domain` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`new_domain`),
  UNIQUE KEY `new_domain_UNIQUE` (`new_domain`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Note: there are additional 3 fields but I do not query them, omitted for brevity.

Example:

```
new_domain
------------------------
http://sub.example.com
```

I want to make a query that identifies the shared name `example.com` in the three tables as follows:

Query:

```
SELECT `new_random`.`new_domain`,`prefix_random`.`domain`,`noprefix_random`.`domain`
FROM `myscheme`.`new_random`
JOIN `myscheme`.`prefix_random`
# the substring to extract the part: sub.example.com
ON substring_index(`new_random`.`new_domain`,'http://',-1) = `prefix_random`.`domain`
JOIN `myscheme`.`noprefix_random`
# by adding sub, it becomes: sub.example
ON CONCAT('sub.',`noprefix_random`.`domain`) = `new_domain`,`prefix_random`;
```

The expected output is:

```
http://sub.example.com, sub.example.com, example.com
```

The query lasts forever. If I limit the output to small number using L

```
LIMIT 10;
```

I get results. The records number is not too larges. `prefix_random` contains 620062, `noprefix_random` contains , and the 62294, and the 588380 records.

What is the problem? Can you help me make the query run?

Comment: Note, primary keys are a) keys and b) always unique. A secondary key on the same is unnecessary.

Comment: Each of my tables has a primary key. What are you trying to point? I am not getting your point sorry.

Comment: You xxx_UNIQUE keys are not needed because the same field is a primary key.

Comment: @danblack this does not harm. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to deal with domains is to use [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) that has the [reverse](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) function on them and index this generated columns. This way a significant amount of queries can be `WHERE domain LIKE CONCAT(reverse(const),'%')` and use an index.

Removing `http://` in a query is also an expensive way to do this. Use this in a generated function/index too.

```
 CREATE TABLE `new_random` (
   `new_domain` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`new_domain`))

 INSERT INTO new_random VALUES ('http://a.b.c'),('http://d.e.f')

 ALTER TABLE new_random ADD no_https VARCHAR(500) AS (substring_index(`new_domain`,'http://',-1)), ADD KEY(no_https)

 ALTER TABLE new_random ADD rev_domain VARCHAR(500) AS (REVERSE(no_https)), ADD KEY(rev_domain)


 SELECT * FROM new_random
```

> ```
> new_domain   | no_https | rev_domain
> :----------- | :------- | :---------
> http://a.b.c | a.b.c    | c.b.a     
> http://d.e.f | d.e.f    | f.e.d
> ```

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT new_domain FROM new_random WHERE rev_domain LIKE 'c.b.%'
```

> ```
> id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                   
> -: | :---------- | :--------- | :--------- | :---- | :------------ | :--------- | :------ | :--- | ---: | -------: | :-----------------------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | new_random | null       | range | rev_domain    | rev_domain | 2003    | null |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd04422fbf0f7d3c688ddbe14c735d16)*

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a full answer with detailed syntax?

Comment: The new best way is in MySQL 8.0.13 or 14+ which supports making indexes on expressions or functions by the way.